# How do I calculate the averages of all the columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, average

I am working on a table with over 100 columns, many of them are boolean in case this is relevant, as I need to use avg(variable_name::int) to take each boolean column average.

Now, I want to take the average of all columns at the same time. How do I do that ?

Thank you very much.

I'll try to be more clear:
I want all the averages of all variables from A to ZZ. Some of them are integers, some are booleans, that's the sole reason why I mencioned the booleans.

```
PK     A  **** GZ ***   ZZ
--------------------------
1      T  ****  F ***    T
2      T  ****  F ***    T
3      F  ****  T ***    T
4      F  ****  F ***    F
5      T  ****  F ***    T
```

Comment: Sounds like you should normalize your database. :-(

Comment: Could you explain this better to me ? Thanks ; ) I think I know what normalize is but I don't understand why if I normalize it it will solve my problem. I am very new into this.

Comment: Basically, there are not a whole lot of reasonable reasons to have a table with 100+ columns, it's likely that you are duplicating a lot of data in there that would be better off in other tables.  Google around with "database normalization", "data modeling", etc.

Comment: grow information to rows, not to columns. normalize your database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no real sneaky or tricky ways to do this.  You might be able to build a dynamic query using the data dictionary, but that's really not recommended.

If you honestly need the average of 100 different columns, you're going to have to type `avg()` 100 times.

I do agree with the above comment, however, that it is likely that you DB would benefit greatly from some normalization.  This is especially true if you have a bunch of columns named 'Something##` where ## is a series of numbers.

Comment: Why it is not recommended to build a dynamic query using the data dictionary ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I don't understand your question. If you start with a table like this:

```
PK     A
--------
1      T
2      T
3      F
4      F
5      T
```

What answer do you expect to get to the question, "What is the average value of column A?"

Comment: I don't understand the question either. What is the average of a boolean? Somewhat True? Not quite false?

Comment: I edited the original post, I want the averages from A to ZZ. :) Thank you !

Comment: "Percentage marked true" is fuzzy if the column allows nulls.

If you averaged column A above (using avg(cast("A" as integer))) you'd get 0.6. But if, say, row "3" were null instead of FALSE, the same query would return 0.75.